# Ping website url from cronjob apache

Tags: cron

I need to setup simple cronejob to ping my website url every 2 minutes, what i did for now make no effect, can somebody help me write simple ping cronjob?

Here is what i have for now

```
2   *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/api/get.php?refresh=yes
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make no effect"? Did the http server not get called? Did you get an error? Does the cron job not fire? _Be precise_.

Comment: Did not fire up at all

Comment: Well, then 1. check the cron daemon and 2. check if you defined the entry to that crontab in the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

This might help:

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   wget -q -O - "http://example.com/api/get.php?refresh=yes" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

> Every 2 minutes (15 in the article), ping the specified file without
>   any output whatsoever. Just a silent ping to execute my script,
>   nothing more, nothing less.

Source: https://wp-mix.com/cron-notes-ping-external-url-with-no-output/